# Error 400 bad request - invalid query

Tags: android

I created some fusion tables, API key, enabled fusion tables on API services, but I have a problem When try to search some data in an app with app inventor.

When I click on button to search and return data, it's returning `400 bad request Invalid Query; Parse error near &#39;SELECT&#39;line 1,position 0)` in both emulator and cell phone.

Attached a link with the print of the error on emulator and the blocks on app inventor that I created.

What's wrong? could you help me please?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem with you Data part,

Its might be possible `you are not passing correct data to API`, try to read document of your API deeply, and try again it will surely works.

Also might be possible so system error in header.

```
but first you need to check your request data part.
```

Read this article : http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc4918.html#STATUS_422